# Controlling jar name from internal repository maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have created an internal repository(Libs) and places my jars in folder hierarchy as showed below

[image]

here is my POM where i am creating repository and specifying dependency for common-jar-1.0.jar

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>in-project</id>
        <name>In Project Repo</name>
        <url>file://${basedir}/libs</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>common</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-jar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mediator</groupId>
        <artifactId>mediator-jar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I want my POM to accept my jar with name **common.jar** ,how can i do it.

currently it will accept only **common-jar-1.0.jar**, 
can we exclude the version from jar name some how??
Please Help

Comment: This is bit unusual. Why are you doing this? Is your intention to build assembly? If yes, you don't have to do all this.

Comment: No, the common.jar is generated with some automatic process and we don't want to re name the name because in every document and other modules common.jar name is used

Comment: If all your modules are built using maven, you don't have to worry about version name getting appended in jar file name.

Comment: if i exclude the version name from common-jar-1.0.jar and make it common-jar.jar then maven could not resolve the dependency for common, it search for common-jar-1.0.jar in internal repository.

Comment: That is my problem....I want maven to search common.jar so that i can rename common-jar-1.0.jar to common.jar, which is my project requirement right now.

Comment: @rahul-tyagi - I think installing the `common.jar` with the  `install-file` goal will solve your problem. You don't need to change the `common.jar` creation process on the one side, and you will get the versioned jar that fits the maven requirements on another side

Comment: could you share a demo

Answer (score 1):

The following will install the `common.jar` with version `1.0`into the local repository `~/.m2/repository`

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path to common.jar> -DgroupId=common -DartifactId=common-jar -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

after that you can define the dependency as usual

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>common</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-jar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: it will configure the name for the generated-jar of my current project i.e. for harmonic in my case, not for common.

Comment: Yes, I see that my answer is not that you need

Comment: it can work.... but I have to use Internal repo..... otherwise every person will have to deploy the jar in repository using this command to make the code run on there machine.

Comment: See the documentation of the goal, you can pass the repo path as an argument

Comment: [install:install-file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html ) see the [localRepositoryPath](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html#localRepositoryPath) parameter